# UPDATE after running a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a planning tool that can import a view or a table from SQL Server. I only import records from a table tblPlanning with a status 'to plan'. After the import, which is executed from the planning tool, I want the status for the imported records to become 'planned'.
I thought I could use a trigger to run a stored procedure after the view vExportPlanning has been called, but it seems triggers are only for UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT statements.
Can someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks!

Comment: At the end of stored procedure write a update statement to update status of processed records

Comment: As @Prdp said, this should be an SP. Can your planning tool fire an SP? What you might not want to do is have the records update fully automatically once called in case of errors in the planning tool (ie, software crashes loading records, but SQL server has alrerady updated the records)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this while selecting or Update

I recommend you to do while select, as below

```
Select col1,col2,....,'Planned' as status  from tblPlanning 
where status='Plan'
```

in query you will be select all the column with '*'.Here replace * by column names.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reason why you really shouldn't update data, when it is just selected. Sure, your view would be read by your application, work on the data and update rows by simply reading the view. This might sound like a quick way of synchronizing something and such, but imagine you want to test the view. You would get in trouble with accidentally updated rows, just because you tried to retrieve some data.

So triggering something before/instead of/after a select doesn't make sense regarding a "good" design.

As the others mentioned (which I completely agree to) you should use stored procedures or functions returning tables. The latter one would mean, you have a function, that basically behaves like a view, but in it you have the opportunity to run code for updating the returned data.

Depending on what sort of updates and inserts in your application lead to similar problems, you might also have a look at the concept of cursors.